# database columns: post_title vs post_name

Tags: posts, database, multi-language

I changed post_title, post_contents, and post_name to allow for utf by changing collating sequence to: utf8_general_ci

Then using add new post, I type for the title three Hebrew ALEFs.
The post_title is in Hebrew in the database, but the post_name has this value:

%d7%90%d7%90%d7%90

According to Charmap, ALEF has a hex value of 05D0.
So what does the d790 represent?  Some other encoding?

I'm looking to write a program to mass upload a bunch of posts, so I need to know what to put in the post_name field, and what it is used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's the [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) version of your text.

```
<?php
echo urldecode('%d7%90%d7%90%d7%90');
?>
```

outputs:

```
אאא
```

`post_name` is the slug, so the characters have to be URL-safe.

Comment: But wouldn't the encoded hex have to match what CharMap.exe shows?

Comment: And I'm storing the Hebrew words in a custom post type which will be used accessed via ShortCodes on real "pages", so if I never intend to display the page, can I leave the post_name null?

Comment: @NealWalters - it's not hexadecimal encoding, it's a different format.

Comment: @NealWalters - you probably can leave them null, I've never tried though, so not sure what other side effects that may have.